# How to get the category

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a cycle that outputs products

```
<?php
$args = array('post_type' =>
'product');
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
foreach ($loop->posts as $have_post) : ?>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
    <a href="
                  <?php
                  $permalink = get_post_permalink($have_post->ID);
                  echo $permalink;
                  ?>
                  " class="goods__item">
      <div class="goods__text">
        <?php
        echo $have_post->name; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="goods__img">
        <?php
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($have_post->ID, 'full', array('alt' => $have_post->post_title, 'data-product_id' => $have_post->ID)); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="goods__name"><?php echo $have_post->post_title; ?></div>
      <div class="goods__price">
        <?php
        $price = get_post_meta($have_post->ID, '_price', true);
        echo $price; ?> руб.
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Need to show the category of current product here. I cant get the category. Please help

```
<div class="goods__text"><?php echo $have_post->name; ?></div>
```

Comment: Does that object *have* a `name` property?  If you output the entire object (`print_r($have_post);`) what does it contain?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with more details. What is output if you do `var_dump($have_post); die()` inside of your loop? Is there event a `category` or `categories` key on the `$have_post` object?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `get_the_terms` to get the correct terms. I believe it's `product_cat` the correct taxonomy.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $have_post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
    $product_cat_name = get_cat_name($product_cat_id); 
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try get_the_category( $post->ID );

Comment: Not working
http://joxi.ru/a2Xjpk8tQWBzDr